# Failed to verify bitcode in TNSWidgets.framework/TNSWidgets

Tags: ios, iphone, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

[image]

I am working with `Nativescript iOS app`, when trying to create an Enterprise Archive using `XCode`. App builds fine but fails with the following error when Enterprise distribution is selected. Please help me to resolve this.

```
Failed to verify bitcode in TNSWidgets.framework/TNSWidgets:
error: Bundle only contains bitcode-marker /var/folders/5d/kv3n6r795l156_mwk8lzpfv00000gn/T/IDEDistributionOptionThinning.Sgt/Payload/hektor.app/Frameworks/TNSWidgets.framework/TNSWidgets (arm64)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: May I know which command did you use to build the app?

Comment: I am having the same issue, please let me know if you find a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved issue using this command. Go to your project directory and run this command in *terminal*

`tns build ios --release --forDevice`

Then you could get your `ipa` file from this location

`../your_project_directory/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphoneos/yourappname.ipa`

Comment: it did worked  !!! Thanks ! ...i had to insert my provision uuid but it worked !
tns build ios --release --provision {{provision UUID}}  --forDevice